# How do I add appointments to effort sum?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I have set up my appointments as below in my `work.org`.

```
* Work                                  :work:
** Client 1 Work
   <2020-06-03 Wed 09:00-10:00>
** Client 2 Work
   <2020-06-03 Wed 18:00-19:00>
```

And this is my org-agenda

```
Day-agenda (W23):
Wednesday   3 June 2020
               8:00...... ----------------
  work:        9:00-10:00 Client 1 Work                                                   :work::
              10:00...... ----------------
              10:14...... now - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
              12:00...... ----------------
              14:00...... ----------------
              16:00...... ----------------
  work:       18:00-19:00 Client 2 Work                                                   :work::
              20:00...... ----------------
```

But when I go for my column view `C-c C-x C-c` in my agenda view, I notice that it my 1 hour appointments do not get added to my estimated effort or Actual effort.

[image]

I have setup the following in my `.emacs`

```
;; under custom-set-variables

'(org-agenda-time-grid
     (quote
      ((daily today require-timed remove-match)
       (800 1000 1200 1400 1600 1800 2000)
       "......" "----------------")))

'(org-columns-default-format
     "%25ITEM(Task) %TODO %TAGS %Effort(Estim){:}  %CLOCKSUM(ActTime)")

'(org-agenda-columns-add-appointments-to-effort-sum t)
```

I was hoping that setting `org-agenda-columns-add-appointments-to-effort-sum` as non-nil would help. The help shows the below

```
org-agenda-columns-add-appointments-to-effort-sum is a variable defined in ‘org-agenda.el’.
Its value is t
Original value was nil

Documentation:
Non-nil means the duration of an appointment will add to day effort.
The property to which appointment durations will be added is the one given
in the option ‘org-effort-property’.  If an appointment does not have
an end time, ‘org-agenda-default-appointment-duration’ will be used.  If that
is not set, an appointment without end time will not contribute to the time
estimate.
```

Quoting from the manual - https://orgmode.org/manual/Effort-Estimates.html

> If you switch to column view in the daily/weekly agenda, the effort
>   column summarizes the estimated work effort for each day81, and you
>   can use this to find space in your schedule. To get an overview of the
>   entire part of the day that is committed, you can set the option
>   org-agenda-columns-add-appointments-to-effort-sum. The appointments on
>   a day that take place over a specified time interval are then also
>   added to the load estimate of the day.

My requirement is that my appointments get added up in some way to my column view in agenda mode, so that I know how much time (effort) is already allocated and thus will give me an idea how much more time I can allocate for myself during the day.

Org mode - 9.3.6
Emacs - 26.3

Comment: Does it work if you format the times like this: `<2020-06-03 Wed 09:00>--<2020-06-03 Wed 10:00>`?

Comment: No it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is a bug in org-mode. Looking at the `org-colview.el` code I think that the reason why column view in org agenda can not add entry duration to efforts (even when `org-agenda-columns-add-appointments-to-effort-sum` is set to `t`) is because the function `org-columns--collect-values` which is called on each org entry by `org-agenda-columns` cannot actually get the text property called `duration` at the point where it tries to do that.

The fix below:

- treats property keys starting with `AGENDA_*` (e.g., `AGENDA_TIME`, `AGENDA_DURATION`) in your `org-columns-default-format-for-agenda` as special properties that will query text properties in agenda buffer instead of org properties
- if text properties in agenda buffer does not have `duration` value (`AGENDA_DURATION` key) it queries `Effort` property of the entry instead. This is the opposite behavior compared to what setting `org-agenda-columns-add-appointments-to-effort-sum` to `t` should do (i.e., `duration` overwrites the `Effort` instead of `Effort` overwrites `duration`)
- if the `duration` of the entry is negative (e.g. when you have a entry that spans the midnight `<2020-08-03 Mon 23:00-7:00>`) it adds 24h to the duration so time sums are calculated correctly

Add the following to your init.el:

```lisp
(with-eval-after-load 'org-colview
    ;; adjusted org-agenda-columns function that now calls
    ;; org-agenda-columns--collect-values (see below) instead 
    ;; of org-columns--collect-values
    (defun org-agenda-columns ()
      "Turn on or update column view in the agenda."
      (interactive)
      (org-columns-remove-overlays)
      (if (markerp org-columns-begin-marker)
          (move-marker org-columns-begin-marker (point))
        (setq org-columns-begin-marker (point-marker)))
      (let* ((org-columns--time (float-time))
             (fmt
              (cond
               ((bound-and-true-p org-overriding-columns-format))
               ((bound-and-true-p org-local-columns-format))
               ((bound-and-true-p org-columns-default-format-for-agenda))
               ((let ((m (org-get-at-bol 'org-hd-marker)))
                  (and m
                       (or (org-entry-get m "COLUMNS" t)
                           (with-current-buffer (marker-buffer m)
                             org-columns-default-format)))))
               ((and (local-variable-p 'org-columns-current-fmt)
                     org-columns-current-fmt))
               ((let ((m (next-single-property-change (point-min) 'org-hd-marker)))
                  (and m
                       (let ((m (get-text-property m 'org-hd-marker)))
                         (or (org-entry-get m "COLUMNS" t)
                             (with-current-buffer (marker-buffer m)
                               org-columns-default-format))))))
               (t org-columns-default-format)))
             (compiled-fmt (org-columns-compile-format fmt)))
        (setq org-columns-current-fmt fmt)
        (when org-agenda-columns-compute-summary-properties
          (org-agenda-colview-compute org-columns-current-fmt-compiled))
        (save-excursion
          ;; Collect properties for each headline in current view.
          (goto-char (point-min))
          (let (cache)
            (while (not (eobp))
              (let ((m (org-get-at-bol 'org-hd-marker)))
                (when m
                  (push (cons (line-beginning-position)
                              ;; `org-columns-current-fmt-compiled' is
                              ;; initialized but only set locally to the
                              ;; agenda buffer.  Since current buffer is
                              ;; changing, we need to force the original
                              ;; compiled-fmt there.
                              ;; clavis
                              (org-agenda-columns--collect-values compiled-fmt m))
                        cache)))
              (forward-line))
            (when cache
              (org-columns--set-widths cache)
              (org-columns--display-here-title)
              (when (setq-local org-columns-flyspell-was-active
                                (bound-and-true-p flyspell-mode))
                (flyspell-mode 0))
              (dolist (entry cache)
                (goto-char (car entry))
                (org-columns--display-here (cdr entry)))
              (setq-local org-agenda-columns-active t)
              (when org-agenda-columns-show-summaries
                (org-agenda-colview-summarize cache)))))))

  ;; new function that substitutes org-columns--collect-values
  (defun org-agenda-columns--collect-values (&optional compiled-fmt m)
      "Collect values for columns on the current line.

  Return a list of triplets (SPEC VALUE DISPLAYED) suitable for
  `org-columns--display-here'.

  This function assumes `org-columns-current-fmt-compiled' is
  initialized is set in the current buffer.  However, it is
  possible to override it with optional argument COMPILED-FMT."
      (let ((summaries (get-text-property (point) 'org-summaries)))
        (mapcar
         (lambda (spec)
           (pcase spec
             (`(,p . ,_)
              (let* ((v (or (cdr (assoc spec summaries))
                            ;; first check if p is a special agenda (text) property
                            (when-let* ((prop-p (string-match "^AGENDA_\\(.+\\)" p))
                                        (prop-name (downcase (match-string 1 p))))
                              ;; if property is duration consider effort if it is not set
                              (if (string= prop-name "duration")
                                  (if-let ((dur (org-get-at-bol (intern prop-name))))
                                      ;; if duration is negatie (i.e. time range crossess
                                      ;; midnight) then add 24h to duration
                                      (if (> dur 0.0)
                                          (propertize (org-duration-from-minutes dur)
                                                      'face 'org-scheduled)
                                        (propertize (org-duration-from-minutes
                                                     (+ dur (* 24 60)))
                                                    'face 'org-scheduled))
                                    (org-with-point-at m
                                      (org-entry-get
                                       (point) org-effort-property
                                       'selective t)))
                                (org-get-at-bol (intern prop-name))))
                            (org-with-point-at m
                              (org-entry-get (point) p 'selective t))
                            "")))
                ;; A non-nil COMPILED-FMT means we're calling from Org
                ;; Agenda mode, where we do not want leading stars for
                ;; ITEM.  Hence the optional argument for
                ;; `org-columns--displayed-value'.
                (list spec v (org-columns--displayed-value spec v compiled-fmt))))))
         (or compiled-fmt org-columns-current-fmt-compiled)))))
```

Adding the following setup in `org-agenda-custom-commands`

```lisp
(add-to-list 'org-agenda-custom-commands
             '("j" "Planning Table"
               agenda ""
               ((org-agenda-overriding-header "")
                (org-agenda-span 1)
                (org-agenda-use-time-grid nil)
                (org-agenda-view-columns-initially t)
                (org-columns-default-format-for-agenda
                 "%11AGENDA_TIME(When) %4TODO(Type) %40ITEM(What) %5AGENDA_DURATION(Takes){:}")
                ;; do not show wardings, overdue and overscheduled
                (org-scheduled-past-days 0)
                (org-deadline-past-days 0)
                (org-deadline-warning-days 0)
                ;; skip finished entries
                (org-agenda-skip-deadline-if-done t)
                (org-agenda-skip-scheduled-if-done t))))
```

and with this org file

```
* TODO Buy last minute spaceship tickets
:PROPERTIES:
:Effort:   1:00
:END:
<2020-08-03 Mon>


* TODO Take up space suit from dry cleaning
:PROPERTIES:
:Effort:   1:00
:END:
<2020-08-03 Mon 14:00-14:30>

* Rest well before space flight
<2020-08-03 Mon 22:00-06:00>

* Taxi to space port
<2020-08-04 Tue 07:00-07:30>

* Trip to Mars
<2020-08-04 Tue 08:30>--<2021-01-13 Wed>
```

You should be able to get the following agenda:

[image: Agenda Column View]

Hope this will help for now. Please, mind that this is not a sustainable solution as it will likely break if new versions of org will change org-columns code.

Org 9.3.7. Emacs 26.3

Comment: Filed it as a bug https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2020-08/msg00090.html

Comment: Thanks. Since the solution is mostly already written, can you share it as a patch against Org's code (maint or master branch)?  See https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contribute.html on how to contribute.